# Replaced stars with NA has no effect when data is read from a function in R

Tags: r, missing-data

I have data frame where the missing values are denoted with star sign "*".

I have replaced them with `> mydata[mydata == "*"] <- NA` but when I use `str(mydata)` it shows that the missing values are still "*". Like

```
'data.frame':   117 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ PRICE: Factor w/ 82 levels "*","1000","1020",..: 36 37 39 39 35 34 32 29 27 26 ...
```

As if I have not applied `> mydata[mydata == "*"] <- NA`

Answer (score 1):

I should have used `na.strings = "*"` while [reading](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) the data file.

Comment: FYI: Your code `mydata[mydata == "*"] <- NA` _did_ successfully replace all `*`'s with NAs. It's just that the `*`'s caused those columns to be read in as factors, and replacing the values doesn't alter the factor levels.

Comment: I think you should not have used `na.strings="NA"` since that is the default setting for `na,strings` and it didn't get you success. Instead you should have used `na.strings = "*"` or perhaps `na.strings = c("NA", "*")`

Comment: @DWin, oh yes. I did but put it wrongly here. I'm going to edit my answer now. Thanks.

Comment: following up on @joran's comment; the result of `sum(is.na(mydata$PRICE))`, or `table(is.na(mydata$PRICE))`, or `table(mydata$PRICE,useNA="always")` might be enlightening

Answer (score 1):

It's not `mydata` that would be equal to "*" but rather `mydata$PRICE`

Try one of these , the first of which would coerce to a numeric vector and in the process generate a warning about some values being set to NA which can be ignored, since that was what you wanted in the first place:

```
 mydata$PRICE  <- as.numeric(as.character( mydata$PRICE))

 mydata$PRICE[ mydata$PRICE == "*" ] <- NA

 is.na(my mydata$PRICE) <-  mydata$PRICE == "*"
```